# How to set value of -DefaultProfile (of type IAzureContextContainer) in New-AzSqlSyncMember

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-data-sync

I am trying to create a powershell script to create azure data sync between 2 azure SQL databases.
My member database is on another subscription.

I need to set -DefaultProfile which is of type  on 'New-AzSqlSyncMember' command.
I am not aware of the syntax for setting this parameter.

My current script without -DefaultProfile looks like below:

```
New-AzSqlSyncMember -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                    -ServerName $serverName `
                    -DatabaseName $databaseName `
                    -SyncGroupName $syncGroupName `
                    -Name $syncMemberName `
                    -MemberDatabaseType $memberDatabaseType `
                    -SyncDirection $syncDirection
```

I want to set the value of the subscription field using powershell like in the image below using powershell:

[image: Set Data Sync Member Subscription]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible cross post from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ad3dd3e-314a-4442-957f-da77c17ef85b/how-to-set-value-of-defaultprofile-of-type-iazurecontextcontainer-in-newazsqlsyncmember?forum=azurescripting&prof=required

You want to call [`Connect-AzAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-3.4.0) with the credentials for the account you want to use in the `-DefaultProfile` parameter and store that in a variable. You can use that variable to set the parameter:

```
$DefaultProfile = Connect-AzAccount <params> -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

New-AzSqlSyncMember <params> -DefaultContext $DefaultProfile
```

If this throws a type error that it can't convert from a `PSAzureContext` to a `IAzureContextContainer` there is an [explicit converter available](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/af37e27433527fbcfebe5f52fdc510b4e9ac14e2/src/Accounts/Authentication.ResourceManager/Models/AzureContextConverter.cs).

```
$DefaultProfile = Connect-AzAccount <params> -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$Converter =  New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.AzureContextConverter
$Container =  $converter.ConvertFrom($DefaultProfile, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.Core.IAzureContextContainer], $null, $true)

New-AzSqlSyncMember <params> -DefaultContext $Container
```